# How to compile multiple independent CPP files in one go?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm not asking about the makefile. I have multiple .cpp files for testing purposes. So in terminal, I need to write:

```
g++ test1 -o run1
g++ test2 -o run2
...
```

If the .cpp files are changed, then I'll have to run the above commands again. Is there a solution to this case? Thanks!

I thought makefile couldn't achieve this goal. That's why I asked in that way. I'll leave the above question intact. Below is my makefile, how am I supposed to change it for multiple files?

```
GCC=g++
GFLAGS=-Wall -g -std=c++11 -O3 
SRC=./test1.cpp    
OUT= test1.out    

g:
    $(GCC) $(GFLAGS) $(SRC) -o $(OUT)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OUT) ./*~ ./*.o
```

Comment: So... why not makefile?

Comment: *"I'm not asking about the makefile."* - Well a Makefile is one solution to this problem.

Comment: This isn't a very well explained question.  Please add more details.  Why do you not want to use `make`?  Why do you need to recompile all files if some change?  Are they all for different executables or are they for a single executable?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why not a Makefile? You could use some other builder (e.g. [omake](http://omake.metaprl.org/), [scons](http://scons.org/) ...) but `make` is really done for that task! Please edit your question to explain why `make` is not suitable. And on which operating system & with which compiler?

Comment: A Makefile would be an obvious solution to this, but if you're really insisting on some other solution, this Bash snippet should do the trick : `for i in *.cpp; do g++ "$i" -o "${i%.cpp}"; done;`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know you're not asking about a `Makefile` but for the scenario you described the makefile can be as simple as this (using GNU Make):

```
all: test1 test2
```

That will turn programs `test1.cpp` and `test2.cpp` into executables `test1` and `test2`.

**ADDED NOTES** for amended question

If you want to be able to set the compiler and flags then you could do that using the variables `CXX` for the compiler and `CXXFLAGS` for the compiler flags:

```
CXX := g++ # set the compiler here
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -g -std=c++11 -O3 # flags...
LDFLAGS := # add any library linking flags here...

# List the programs in a variable so adding
# new programs is easier
PROGRAMS := test1 test2

all: $(PROGRAMS)

# no need to  write specific rules for
# your simple case where every program
# has a corresponding source code file
# of the same name and one file per program.

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROGRAMS)
```

**NOTE:** The target `all:` is the default target and it is run when you type `make` with no parameters.

**FINAL EXAMPLE:** where one program takes two input source files so it needs a special rule. The other file still compiles automatically as in the previous examples.

```
CXX := g++ # set the compiler here
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -g -std=c++11 -O3 # flags...

# List the programs in a variable so adding
# new programs is easier
PROGRAMS := test1 test2

all: $(PROGRAMS)

# If your source code filename is different
# from the output program name or if you
# want to have several different source code
# files compiled into one output program file
# then you can add a specific rule for that 
# program

test1: prog1.cpp prog2.cpp # two source files make one program
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROGRAMS)
```

**NOTE:** `$@` simply means the output program file name (`test1`) and `$^` means all the input files listed (`prog1.cpp prog2.cpp` in this case).

Comment: I updated my question. Would you give me some advice in more detail? Thanks!

Comment: @user3156285 Makefiles can become quite complicated for complex projects. But for the case you describe in your question I'll provide some simple examples.

Comment: @user3156285 I added two examples of increasing complexity, hope they help. It may seem a little complicated to begin with but `make` is a very important and widely used tool that is well worth getting to know.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist in not using Make, you could write all the commands into a plain text file and execute it as a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I was under the impresstion that the OP wanted to compile multiple files into one binary, not multiple binaries from multiple files.

---

Just do something like this:

`g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp -o binary`

Comment: I'm afraid each of the mentioned test sources contains its own `main()` function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I see. Disregard this answer as it does not answer the question.