# Makefile for many c++ executables

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I am working on a project where I constantly need to create new c++ executables. They all rely on some common headers and sources files, so I am wondering how to simplify the compilation and Makefile writing.
The best I have come up with so far is something like this:

```
file1: $(BUILDDIR)/$@.o $(COMMON_OBJECTS) $(COMMON_LIBS)
    $(CCCOM) $(CCFLAGS) $(BUILDDIR)/$@.o $(COMMON_OBJECTS) -o $(BINDIR)/$@ $(LIBFLAGS)
```

and then I have to copy this target for each executable I want to add. Ideally I want to define this rule once for arbitrary target and then simply call `make any_file_name`.

Is something like that possible?
How do people organize c++ project with lots of executables? (I am new to c++ and coming from python that is a very natural thing)

Comment: I think this answer does what you want (possible duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860625/how-to-compile-multiple-independent-cpp-files-in-one-go/28860795#28860795

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/igagis/prorab, it allows creating `makefile`s for C++ without  repeating same rules many times

Answer (score 0):

You *could* make it so that each executable corresponds to a single `.cpp` file in a directory (e.g. `executables/foo.cpp`, `executables/bar.bpp`), and then work from there -- this will save you from having to touch the `Makefile` every time you add another one.

You should, probably, also set up your project to create a shared library, which the (light-weight) executables link to. (The executables effectively just doing some command-line parsing, and offloading the actual work to library functions.) This way, you will not end up with the code from those `$(COMMON_OBJECTS)` being replicated in every executable.

Comment: I will read about shared libraries, thanks for the suggestion. Regarding your first solution, I can see how this would work for compiling all the executables at once (by searching for all .cpp files in certain directory) but what if I wanted to only compile one of them?

Comment: @user1830663: You an specify each executable's name individually as a make target...?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example makefile with automatic header dependency generation for you:

```
BUILD := debug
BUILD_DIR := ${BUILD}

CXX := g++

cppflags.debug :=
cppflags.release := -DNDEBUG
cppflags := ${cppflags.${BUILD}} ${CPPFLAGS}

cxxflags.debug :=
cxxflags.release := -O3
cxxflags := ${cxxflags.${BUILD}} ${CXXFLAGS}

ldflags := ${LDFLAGS}
ldlibs := ${LDLIBS}

exes := # Executables to build.

### Define executables begin.

exes += exe1
exe1.obj := exe1.o

exes += exe2
exe2.obj := exe2.o

### Define executables end.

all : ${exes:%=${BUILD_DIR}/%}

.SECONDEXPANSION:

${BUILD_DIR}:
    mkdir -p $@

# Rule to link all exes.
${exes:%=${BUILD_DIR}/%} : ${BUILD_DIR}/% : $$(addprefix ${BUILD_DIR}/,$${$$*.obj}) | $${@D}
    ${CXX} -o $@ ${ldflags} $^ ${ldlibs}

# Rule to compile C sources. And generate header dependencies.
${BUILD_DIR}/%.o : %.cc | $${@D}
    ${CXX} -o $@ -c ${cppflags} ${cxxflags} -MD -MP $<

# Include automatically generated header dependencies.
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(foreach exe,${exes},$(patsubst %.o,${BUILD_DIR}/%.d,${${exe}.obj}))
endif

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Usage example:

```
$ cat exe1.cc 
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; }

$ cat exe2.cc 
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "Hello, world!\n"; }

$ make
mkdir -p debug
g++ -o debug/exe1.o -c     -MD -MP exe1.cc
g++ -o debug/exe1  debug/exe1.o 
g++ -o debug/exe2.o -c     -MD -MP exe2.cc
g++ -o debug/exe2  debug/exe2.o 

$ make BUILD=release 
mkdir -p release
g++ -o release/exe1.o -c -DNDEBUG  -O3  -MD -MP exe1.cc
g++ -o release/exe1  release/exe1.o 
g++ -o release/exe2.o -c -DNDEBUG  -O3  -MD -MP exe2.cc
g++ -o release/exe2  release/exe2.o 

$ make clean
rm -rf debug

$ make BUILD=release clean
rm -rf release
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify everything I'm assuming you have sources `file1.cpp`, `file2.cpp` and so on, and all your files reside in the same directory. Then `Makefile` fragment below will do what you want:

```
all: $(basename $(wildcard file?.cpp))

file%: file%.cpp
```

To make everyhing:

```
make all
```

To make `file1`:

```
make file1
```

To make `file1` and `file2`:

```
make file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks! what if the names dont follow any pattern ?

Comment: @user1830663 - it'll be less convenient... You'll have to write the `all` rule including all the names you have. Or to prefix the names with some string you choose